# Modelling GeoJSON in Swagger

Tags: json, geojson, swagger

I'm trying to add a definition for GeoJSON in a Swagger API that serves JSON. I'm running into some issues with defining the options that GeoJSON has for features.

A single feature can be a choice of `"Point"`, `"MultiPoint"`, `"LineString"`, `"MultiLineString"`, `"Polygon"`, or a `"MultiPolygon"`. Each of these though imposes different constraints on their `coordinates` field. For instance, a point might have a single coordinate consisting of an longtitude latitude pai, while a Polygon might have a field that looks like this:
`[ [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ] ]`.

I've looked around but there seems no elegant solution to this problem except by just defining the geometry as a `string` instead of a complex object like this. This means a loss of information, and makes it undesirable to port APIs based on a Swagger specification because input strings will have to be parsed to an object first.

The GeoJSON objects look like [this](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples).

What I've got so far is this:

```
  "Feature": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
        },
        "geometry": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Geometry"
        },
        "type" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "properties": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    }
}
```

And the geometry definition looks like this:

```
"Geometry": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type":{
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["Point","MultiPoint","LineString","MultiLineString","Polygon","MultiPolygon"]
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "number",
        "example": [4.49965, 52.06891]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked this gist file: [geometry_geojson-yaml](https://gist.github.com/bubbobne/fe5f2db65acf039be6a9fd92fc9c7233#file-geometry_geojson-yaml)

Comment: This is a three-year old question my friend, at the time the spec didn't support this at all!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no way to describe that using Swagger. You can describe a single type, but not something that would accept/produce all types.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the most recent attempt is this one: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/OlivierMartineau/GeoJSON/1.0.1

It was created by an "OlivierMartineau" aka "zitoun" or "zit0un" who used the already mentioned (by @jmini) "[gist](https://gist.github.com/bubbobne/fe5f2db65acf039be6a9fd92fc9c7233/forks)" by "bubbobne" as well as one of the forks by "idkw" as the foundation for his model.